# Is it possible to kill session or force session expiry in Tomcat either active or inactive?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, timeout, kill

I need to know if its possible to set a forced session time-out at a WEB SERVER level, that basically after x period of time, kicks the user from the session either it is active or inactive or better saying WEBSERVER to delete the session linked to the client.
Can this be achieved without development intervention on the application side? 
Is this possible to do it with Tomcat? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it through Tomcat default web.xml configuration

```
<session-config>
   <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>    <!-- 10 minutes -->
</session-config>
```

For full reference: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/appdev/web.xml.txt

The file can be located in conf/web.xml (relative to your tomcat installation)

**Edit**

You can also invalidate a given session using `session.invalidate()` method

Comment: Sorry, that's not what i want. Time-out is probably not the right word to describe what i want. What i want is to force kick the user session. So, its not really an inactivity time-out..

Comment: In this case, you will have to do it programmatically using session.invalidate(). If I understood correctly

Answer (score 0):

you can set the time when you create a session using  `setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval);` 
either make it constant or fetch from database depending on users time..!